# CSV Manipulation Unique Entries

Tags: python, shell, csv

I have a couple CSV files with the following format (without the headers)

file1.csv :

```
firstname,lastname
andrew,harling
brad,dominic
pete,petey
```

file2.csv :

```
firstname,lastname,blood_group
andy,robbins,O+
brad,dominic,AB-
pete,petey,B+
```

Aim : Merge these 2 files with some constraints :

1. Ensure all unique entries are present in the output csv (refer to sample below)
2. In case an entry is found (match according to (firstname, lastname)), then only take the entry from file2.csv (with the blood group)

Sample output.csv :

```
firstname,lastname,blood_group
andrew,harling
andy,robbins,O+
brad,dominic,AB-
pete,petey,B+
```

I tried the following approach :

1. Copy file2.csv to file2_2col.csv (copied only the first 2 columns over)
2. Now removed duplicated from file1 (found in file2_2col) using :

   comm -23 <(sort file1.csv)  <(sort file2_2col.csv) > file1_without_duplicates.csv
3. Merged file1_without_duplicates.csv and file2.csv using :

   cat *.csv | sort - u > unique.csv

But this still contained duplicates like :

Erroneous output.csv :

```
firstname,lastname,blood_group
brad,dominic
pete,petey
andrew,harling
andy,robbins,O+
brad dominic AB-
pete,petey,B+
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: for reference, I do not have any of these headers in the files; only added here for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short awk program

```sh
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} 
  {name = $1 OFS $2}
  NR == FNR {f1[name] = 1; next}
  name in f1 {delete f1[name]}
  {print}
  END { for (name in f1) print name }
' file{1,2}.csv
```

```
firstname,lastname,blood_group
andy,robbins,O+
brad,dominic,AB-
pete,petey,B+
andrew,harling
```

Comment: Ack, these are just placeholders to convey problem statement; my actual data does not contain any spaces or names for that matter :)

Comment: tried this awk based script; still observing duplicates like :
brad dominic
brad dominic AB-

Comment: Did you test with the exact sample data you put in the question? If not, then there must be differences between your two input files. If the files have DOS-style line endings,  then one record will be `brad dominic\r` and the "matching" record will be `brad dominic AB-\r` -- the names are in fact different. You might try using `dos2unix` on the input files.

Comment: got the issue; it's related to the structure of the csv file
(updated sample input in the question to reflect actual csv structure -> the commas)

Comment: Updated my answer to handle commas,

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution:

```
$ cat file{1,2}.csv
firstname,lastname
andrew,harling
brad,dominic
pete,petey
firstname,lastname,blood_group
andy,robbins,O+
brad,dominic,AB-
pete,petey,B+

$ gawk -F "," '{a[$1 "," $2] = $3} END{for(i in a){(a[i]=="") ? x=i : x=i "," a[i]; print x}}' file{1,2}.csv
andy,robbins,O+
firstname,lastname,blood_group
pete,petey,B+
andrew,harling
brad,dominic,AB-
```

Comment: updated sample input to reflect actual csv structure